# CMake: How to handle a missing FindXXX script in 2.6 but present in 2.8

Tags: dependencies, cmake, compatibility

The script FindHDF5.cmake is available since CMake 2.8. My software runs on various systems with either CMake 2.8 or 2.6.

When I use find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED) it works in 2.8 but of course not in 2.6. I was therefore thinking to copy FindHDF5.cmake in my project. But this is 1. ugly and 2. unmaintainable.

How do you handle such a situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use

```
find_package(HDF5 REQUIRED)
```

then you should really require CMake 2.8 or later.

If you must run with CMake 2.6, then you should provide your own FindHDF5.cmake.

You can use conditional logic based on the CMake version if you must, such as:

```
if("${CMAKE_VERSION}" VERSION_LESS 2.8)
  # Use your own "CMake/FindHDF5.make"...
  set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
endif()
```

However, the CMAKE_VERSION variable was not available until CMake 2.6.3, so you'll have to require at least CMake 2.6.3 in order to use such a construct reliably.

See also:

- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable:CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR
- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable:CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
- http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable:CMAKE_VERSION

Comment: I think I will end up with some conditional logic but rather based on 1. Try Find_package 2. if failed, set cmake_module_path and try again. This is what Andre has proposed in a comment.

Comment: That is better than a version based conditional - go for it. If Andre adds an answer to that effect, I'll even upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cmake's module path to anything you want:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} /opt/common/cmake-backports)
```

There unlimited ways of populating custom files on your (Linux) distribution. You could make a .deb/.rpm yourself to put Module-files in /opt/common/.. or in /usr/share... Or you provide an NFS-network directory with those files.

Maybe the easiest is to update the cmake 2.6-hosts to cmake-2.8. For most distribution you'll find ready-made backported packages. (E.g. Ubuntu 10.4)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Given that I don't have control on the machines where the software will be compiled, I have to embed the FindHDF5.cmake script and use it if it is not available on the system. Is that correct ? I was hoping there would be a standard way of doing so, instead of having a if... else...

Comment: What do you mean by if-else? Don't bother, just put the FindXYZ.cmake into your project and add the path first to the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH. If the same Find-file exists in /usr/share/cmake it will be overriden by the "local" one.

Comment: "If the same Find-file exists in /usr/share/cmake it will be overriden by the "local" one."
This is exactly the problem, because I want the one in /usr/share/cmake to be the default one, the "local" one be used only if it is missing in /usr/share/cmake.

Comment: @Barth, Why not try an "ordinary" find_package, check if the package was found. If not, set the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to point to  and than call find_package again. Or perhaps use the NO_MODULE option the second call of find_package.

Comment: @Andre Thanks, this is a good idea, I'll do that. If you create a new reply, I'll accept it.